# JQuery: can I submit values from inputs that aren't in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Simple as that: I have some inputs that are rendered inside another form element, but I want to submit then individually.

I tried "serializing" the div that contains them, but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

My code:

```
var form = $("#my_div");
var get_data = $(form).serialize();  /* Get #my_div inputs value */
$.get(self.url_form_rendering, get_data,
function (data){
    /* handle server response */
})
```

Serialize returns "", any ideas that don't involve redesigning the layout to avoid form nesting?

Comment: can you post your html also?

Comment: It really doesn't matter in this case. The html of the div is a bunch of controls provided dynamically by the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the serialize make sure the input have their own ID's and try this code:

```
$('#my_div *').serialize();
```

Comment: @Alvaro :) Sorry, To be sure make a habit of giving an id and name.
That was my problem before when it doesn't serialize :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

Do it by building `get_data` as an object:

```
var get_data = {
    field1: $("#field1").val(),
    field2: $("#field2").val(),
    ...
};
```

You can use the above for just the extra elements. For the form, you can add them with a loop:

```
$("#formid :input").each(function() {
    get_data[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

You could also give the elements outside the form a class, and select them and iterate similarly.

Comment: Good approach, I thought of it.. but I'm afraid I'll miss an input since the inputs are dynamically generated by the server... Maybe iterating over elements with a name... I'll give it a shot

Comment: See my updated answer for how to get the elements in the form.

Comment: The serialization with * worked like a charm! Both are good approaches... your code it's very explicit and readable, but for this particular case I favor the wildcard